# AngularJS Material Layout Attribute inside Directives

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I cannot get the layout attributes to work inside directives for some reason.
Here is an example with layout column inside a directive with [plunk link](http://plnkr.co/edit/C5DjtkNzMp3vlxbJKlii?p=preview). Any solution or idea to fix these?

**Directive**

```
<div style="width: 800px; height: 800px;">
    <div layout="column" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background: red"></div>
    <div layout="column" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background: green"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing layout="row"  on the outer div